# How to align a paragraph to the bottom-left of an image?

Tags: html, css, image, position

I'd like to get the result as showed in the image below, centered horizontally, just below the nav bar.

[image: paragraph to the bottom-left of an image]

this is my code now, I tried but I don't manage to center the div...
https://jsfiddle.net/L1drp0b7/

```css
#contactsul {
font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 100;
    list-style: none;
    position: static;
  display : inline-block;
  vertical-align : bottom;
  width :5%;
}

#image {
  width:30%;
  display:inline-block;
}

#contacts {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contacts">
<ul id="contactsul">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Fruit</li>
  <li>Meat</li>
</ul>
<img src="http://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/9/9552-a-green-apple-on-a-dark-background-pv.jpg" id="image">
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```css
#contactsul {
font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 100;
    list-style: none;
    position: static;
  display : inline-block;
  vertical-align : bottom;
  width :10%;
}

#image {
  width:30%;
  display:inline-block;
}

#contacts {
  width:100%;
  text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<div id="contacts">
<ul id="contactsul">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Fruit</li>
  <li>Meat</li>
</ul>
<img src="http://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/9/9552-a-green-apple-on-a-dark-background-pv.jpg" id="image">

</div>
```

Solution 2:

```css
#contactsul {
font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 100;
    list-style: none;
    position: static;
  display : inline-block;
  vertical-align : bottom;
  width :20%;
}

#image {
  width:60%;
  display:inline-block;
}

#contacts {
  margin : 0 auto;
  width : 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contacts">
<ul id="contactsul">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Fruit</li>
  <li>Meat</li>
</ul>
<img src="http://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/9/9552-a-green-apple-on-a-dark-background-pv.jpg" id="image">

</div>
```

Comment: I've just updated my question, now it works and your way is similar but I need to center in the middle of the screen. I've tried with margin: 0 auto but it doesn't work...

Comment: Hey, here's the new answer for what you want, the div is now aligned

Comment: I added another possible solution, please if this is the answer mark it as best answer

Comment: @alberto96 here's the answer

Comment: The first one it doesn't center precisely 100% but it has a similar result :)

Answer (score 0):

just take two elements indide div.
onde image and another text.

```
float: right to img
```

and adjust text to bottom by giving padding or margin-top

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.a{margin:140px;
width:500px;

}
img {
    float: right;
}
div.b{
width:48%;
padding-top:90px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="a">
<img src="yourimage" width=50% height=50% />
<div class="b">add text  what you want here.
adjsut padding and margin suitable for your requirement</div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can do this by multiple ways

Answer (score 0):

Taking your original html structure, this will work for you:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
  </ul>
  <img src="http://www.qqxxzx.com/images/apple-picture/apple-picture-10.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background:#fff;
}
.wrapper img {
  display:inline-block;
}
.wrapper .list {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  style-type:none;
}
```

See it in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x9wLqfry

Hope it helps a bit.